# Gradle stuck at Configuring projects

Tags: linux, jenkins, gradle

I have written a small spring boot application with a Rest controller. On my Windows 10 laptop, when I build it using gradle 3.5, it works fine. I had uploaded the code to git and pull it in Jenkins on Red Hat Linux. gradle clean is stuck forever at configuring projects. I had to abort the run.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `build.gradle` it's very difficult to know but it's possible that the `.gradle` folder is a task output for one of your tasks. Eg

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from 'foo'
    into '.'
}
```

Notice how the project folder is now a task output which is bad (since the `.gradle` folder is also a task output). Gradle will likely hang here waiting for a read lock whilst it owns a write lock.

In general, it's best to use a separate directory per task... usually a subdirectory under the `${buildDir}` directory for files which aren't comitted to source control